# Выгрузка данных из таблицы

Tags: sqlite

Могу ли я выгружать строки с id = 11 по id = 25 или , например, id = 245 по id = 500. Посоветуйте, как это сделать, спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id >= 11 AND id <= 25;
```

Это уж совсем основы, сорри, даже я знаю.

Comment: Спасибо огромное всем.